# Why does Neovim start inserting tabs into my files after I have been editing them for a while?

Tags: javascript, vim, eslint, neovim

My local and global `.eslintrc` files both specify:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {
    "indent": ["error", 2, { "SwitchCase": 1 }],
}
```

The potentially relevant parts of my `init.vim` are:

```
scriptencoding utf-8

Plug 'moll/vim-node'
Plug 'mxw/vim-jsx'
Plug 'othree/javascript-libraries-syntax.vim'
Plug 'styled-components/vim-styled-components', { 'branch': 'main' }

set autoindent
set breakindent
set shiftwidth=2
set smartindent

function! LintThisFile()
    set nomodifiable
    if(&filetype =~ 'javascript')
        " --rule etc is a recent addition, after the problems began
        keepjumps silent! exec "! ".GetProjectPath()."/node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix --rule 'indent: ["error", 2, {SwitchCase: 1}]' %"
    elseif (&ft =~ 'htm')
        keepjumps silent! exec '!tidy -m %'
    endif
    set modifiable
    edit
endfunction

function! LintFixThisFile()
    if &modifiable
        let l:line = line('.')
        let l:col = col('.')
        let l:view = winsaveview()
a       keepjumps exec 'silent! %s/\t/  /g'
        if (index(['javascript', 'javascript.jsx', 'html'], &filetype) >= 0)
            silent! call LintThisFile()
        else
            exec 'silent! normal! gg=G'
        endif
        silent! call cursor(l:line, l:col)
        silent! call winrestview(l:view)
    endif
endfunction

function! GetProjectPath()
    let l:cwd = expand('%:h')
    if (l:cwd ==# '')
        let l:cwd = getcwd()
    endif
    let l:raw_path=system('(cd '.l:cwd.' && git rev-parse --show-toplevel)')
    if (l:raw_path=~# 'Not a git repository')
        return l:cwd.'/'
    elseif (l:raw_path =~ '\n')
        return split(l:raw_path, '\n')[-1]
    else
        return l:raw_path
    endif
endfunction
```

When I start out, everything auto-formats as expected with two spaces and no tabs for each level of indentation. But after a while, this changes and it starts inserting tabs.

Any idea why?

I'm wondering perhaps if one of my plug-ins is writing over a global or global-ish variable used by another one for formatting. That would explain why the problem only appears after I have been working in Neovim for a while. Something similar to this: https://github.com/mxw/vim-jsx/pull/177#issuecomment-443910457. It would also explain why everything used to work but now doesn't -- i.e. it may be a problem introduced by a plug-in upgrade.

Comment: Is the global `expandtab` setting changed when the behaviour changes? Without plugins, that's what would control tabs vs spaces, and maybe you have a plugin that changes that setting in some particular circumstances? (I would consider that a bug in the plugin...)

Comment: I think I have the same problem. It usually happens, when I paste something into vim from outside via <Ctrl + V>, but it also happens without doing it. Sometimes it shows up after an hour, sometimes even after just a few minutes. Did you find a solution for this? So far only closing nvim and reopening fixes it.

Comment: writing into vim `:set nopaste` after I pasted text fixed it for me. More info about this here: https://coderwall.com/p/if9mda/automatically-set-paste-mode-in-vim-when-pasting-in-insert-mode